# subprocessing library in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

```
import subprocess

sample_file_directory = "..." # directory where file is
SCRIPT_DIR = "..." # directory where script is

p = subprocess.Popen([SCRIPT_DIR,sample_file_directory,'min','edgelen'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE) 
min_side_len, err = p.communicate()
print len(err)
```

So i have this script that analyzes .ply files (3d file format) and gives me data about the file. I am trying to find out in my directory which files are corrupted and which aren't. So I am trying to use the subprocess library to run the script to find an arbitrary feature of the .ply files (in this case the minimum edge length) If err has anything in it, it means it couldn't retrieve the arbitrary feature and the file is corrupted. Here, I am only running it on one file. However, I keep getting an error.

```
p = subprocess.Popen([SCRIPT_DIR,sample_file_directory,'min','edgelen'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me figure out why I am getting this error? Both my data directory and script directory are valid. Also, sorry if I left anything out that's important. First time posting.

Comment: What is the actual script name, and are you giving that to the `Popen` call?

Comment: The script is called mesh_info, and it can be found in a package called trimesh2. And yes I am calling it in Popen with SCRIPT_DIR because I include the script name within the directory.

Comment: You can get this error when the script being called in Popen is a text file with a shebang that subprocess can't find. So for example if your script begins `#!python` rather than `#!/usr/local/env python`, you'll get this error. (subprocess.Popen doesn't have access to your $PATH)

Comment: One other thing it could potentially be is that you're trying to run a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system without the 32-bit libraries installed. I actually ran into this issue earlier today. A fix is documented [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/133460). I don't know anything about your system, so this may be completely irrelevant advice, but I figured it wouldn't hurt to mention it.

Comment: Ah yes! That was the problem! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"One other thing it could potentially be is that you're trying to run a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system without the 32-bit libraries installed. I actually ran into this issue earlier today. A fix is documented here. I don't know anything about your system, so this may be completely irrelevant advice, but I figured it wouldn't hurt to mention it." Dan Albert. He came up with the answer to the solution! Thanks so much Dan!

Answer (score 0):

subprocess.Popen() won't combine path components for you. From what I see, you're only providing a directory. You'll need to add the target executable's name to the path being given to Popen. Try the following:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR,SCRIPT_NAME),sample_file_directory,'min','edgelen'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: That should be os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, SCRIPT_NAME). i.e., the two should be passed directly, not part of a list.

Comment: I should have specified sorry that the directory already includes the script name.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, JJC. I couldn't remember which it was.
OP: I'd have to agree with everyone else and say that your program probably just can't find the script you're trying to run. Using the absolute path shouldn't have that issue, so I'd try printing out the path just before the call to Popen(). Might try copying the full path that is printing and dumping it into a shell to make sure it can run.

Other things to look out for are crossing filesystems and following symlinks. In theory, all this should be handled for you, but stranger things have happened :)

Answer (score 0):

Is your SCRIPT_DIR variable the absolute path or a relative path valid in the location you're running the script?  If it's the latter, it may not work, as the subprocess may start in a different environment that has a different working directory.

Comment: No, unfortunately I am using the absolute path

Comment: Hmmm. Have you tried passing the SCRIPT_DIR, sample_file_directory, etc. as an assembled string (instead of a list) and using the shell=True option?  If your command relies on shell expansion (e.g. of ~ or other wildcard or shell features, these will not work unless you use this latter approach.  Barring that, have you tried running other commands (like /bin/date or something simple that you know works and you know its location)?

Comment: shell=True might help for testing, but for the final program I would make sure it gets removed. As the program is now, you won't run into security issues, but it would be easy to forget that detail if you were to come back later and allow any of the parameters to be specified by the user. See the warning under http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments for an explanation of why you should be cautious with shell=True.

Comment: I completely second DanAlbert's warning about the shell=True option.  I only suggested it in case shell expansion was the reason for the command not being found, but I should have included the advice about not using it in production. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([SCRIPT_DIR,sample_file_directory,'min','edgelen'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Notice this part:

```
Popen([SCRIPT_DIR,sample_file_directory,'min','edgelen']
```

Now, see, you already know that `subprocess` takes a list. But the problem is that you are passing the directory as part of the list. The list is formatted like this:

[command, arg1, arg2...]

Now, when you run that command, you are doing this:

[SCRIPT_DIR -> command
sample_file_directory -> arg1
'min' -> arg2
'edgelen' -> arg3]

See the problem? You are passing the script's directory as the command to run and the script's name as an argument. Import the `os` module and do this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR,sample_file_directory),'min','edgelen'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This does this:

[SCRIPT_DIR and sample_file_directory joined together -> command
'min' -> arg1
'edgelen' -> arg2]

`os.path.join` automatically adds the path separator.

Comment: Why am I joining together the script directory and file directory? I should have stated that the script directory includes the script name and the script takes the file as an argument.

Comment: Ohhh...well...then it simply can't find the script. I thought the SCRIPT_DIR was just the folder and sample_file_directory was the script name. Sorry! It's seriously that Popen can't find your script. Try adding a print statement before the Popen call that prints SCRIPT_DIR so you can make sure it's what you want.